# sketching the graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

how to sketch the graph $|x+y|= m$, when $ m $ is some real number?

I personally can not see any efficient or known method to do so...

Comment: What happens when both $x$ and $y$ are positive? What happens if one of them is negative (and more/less in magnitude) of the second positive quantity?

Comment: I don't know....

Answer (score 2):

We can get a better idea of what the graph might look like by using the fact that $|x| = x$ if $x\geq 0$, and $|x| =-x$ if $x\lt 0$.

$$ |x-y| = m \implies \begin{cases} x-y = m & \text{when}\;x-y\geq 0 \iff x\geq y\\ x-y = -m & \text{when}\;x-y \lt 0\iff x < y\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

A very naive approach to draw this ends up like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** Both $x$ and $y$ are positive(1st quadrant).

Then, the equality changes to $x+y=m$

So draw a line in the first quadrant joining $(0,m)$ and $(m,0)$.

**Case 2:** Both are negative (third quadrant)

Proceed as in 1.

$x+y=-m$.

**Case 3:** 2nd quadrant $(x<0,y>0)$

Note: if $|x|<|y|$, then $x+y$ is positive.
On the other hand, negative.

**Case 4:** proceed as in 3

Comment: both are negative=third quadrant

Comment: Yes, sorry! Edited.